# Which one sounds better: schedule at a time slot or schedule to a time slot?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one sounds better?

> schedule something *at* a time slot

or

> schedule something *to* a time slot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither one of them sounds natural at all to my American English ear. I would either say:

> schedule something *in* a time slot

or

> schedule a time slot *for* something